# PHP - Phalcon <b>Fatal error</b>: Uncaught Error: Class 'Phalcon\Db' not found in

Tags: php, phalcon

I recently entered in a company but I'm currently making an API in Laravel, but the old API was built with Phalcon, but some functions need to be working in a New Server, so I installed the phalcon 4 with php 7.4 but when I try to call the Constant Phalcon\Db::FETCH_OBJ, returns an error that shown

**Fatal error**: Uncaught Error: Class 'Phalcon\Db' not found in

But I the Router, Application and all others stuffs are okay for now, but I'm stuck in that problem, that never happened with me before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Phalcon 4 this is moved to 'Phalcon\Db\Enum'.
The application was probably written in Phalcon 3.

https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/v4.0.6/phalcon/Db/Enum.zep